# Can I see who holds my token in solidity

Tags: solidity, tokens, mapping

I'm learning to code in solidity and have started learning through making an ERC-20 token. I want to
be able to see who is holding the tokens without using a for loop. So far I've mapped each address to see if they're a holder or not. But have no idea how to list all items in that map that are true for let's say a lottery or giving holders more tokens, etc.

```
mapping(address => bool) private isHolder;
```

I'm new so any help appreciated,

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand what your use case is but the below example might help as it returns the array of addresses.

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: NOLICENSE
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

contract holder {
    
    mapping(bool => address[]) holders;
    
    function buyToken() public {
        holders[true].push(msg.sender);
    }
    
    function getHolders() public view returns(address[] memory) {
        return holders[true];
    }
}
```

The above example demonstrates that how you can get all the token holders but still, you need to write logic to avoid duplicates.

Update: To get Nth holder

For that, you have to use EnumerableSet or you can get the length of the array. for example: `holders[true].length`. so the Nth holder is `holders[true][length-1]`.

If you find this use full then please let me know by voting & accepting this answer.

Comment: thank you so much, when it says return holders[true] how would I  find the address of the Nth holder

Comment: @Joop1123 for that you have to use EnumerableSet.

Comment: @Joop1123 updated the answer

Comment: thanks for your help. If i wanted to check to see if an address is part of the holders[true] how would i do that?

Comment: for that, you can maintain this ``` mapping(address => bool) private isHolder;``` or explore EnumerableSet as I said earlier